# I approved a bad answer, but flagged it immediately afterward. Can I get review privileges restored?

Tags: support, review-queues, flags

To clarify, I'm not complaining about a review audit. This was not an audit.

This is the answer in question, it's clearly not an answer:

[Variational autoencoder and reconstruction Log Probability vs Reconstruction error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47070393/variational-autoencoder-and-reconstruction-log-probability-vs-reconstruction-err/53051731#53051731)

I mistakenly clicked approve for this in review, but immediately went back and flagged it as Not an Answer, it shows up as a helpful flag in my flag history.

Since I fixed this immediately can I get my review privileges restored?

Comment: No, why? You failed audits. If this was to be normal procedure we can as well get rid of audits all together. The point of reviewing is that you review correctly. You missed a couple of audits, leading to a review ban. That ban seems legit. That you can flag a deleted answer as NAA would count as a bug, specially if that increases your helpful flag stats.

Comment: @rene: it wasn't an audit. also the answer wasn't deleted when I flagged it. I knew immediately it was a mistake and I went back and flagged it. so No is a respectable answer, but your facts are incorrect. also my helpful flag stats are pretty good, I think.

Comment: I get the value of correcting your mistakes but it isn't like *one* bad review is going to get you banned.  There's more to this story.

Comment: @Nathan It was a correct guess to make without knowing it wasn't. If it wasn't an automatic ban than that means a ban was manually applied. Let's let the person who did it expand on the matter, or not.

Comment: Fair enough, here is the review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21269569 Can you share your flag marked helpful timestamp?

Comment: @NathanHughes hover over the text *helpful* with your mouse. The tooltip should show the timestamp in HH:MM

Comment: @rene: ok thanks. says 18:30:56Z

Comment: That timestamp doesn't make sense. You reviewed that answer at 18:52. It is up to the mods to sort this out with their timeline

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So... I took the liberty of looking at a few of your last reviews, since you brought the topic here. Over the 5 last, there are *three* that you said looked ok where they are very clearly off topic.

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/21278097
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/21277978
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/21278382

Just to be clear: questions that are primarily opinion based (is it ok?) are not "looks ok". Questions that ask "is it possible" are not "looks ok". Questions with images that might explain a problem, or not, behind a link, are not "looks ok".

I don't know if a mod looked at that and decided it was enough, but as a simple user, let me ask you: please don't leave those around anymore.

Comment: Nice find! Just to play a bit of Devil's Advocate for a sec, tho, at least he went **Looks OK** instead of **Requires Editing**. Not ideal, but at least he's not clogging another queue up with that junk

Comment: Heh, fair enough ;)

Comment: thank you for the feedback, I'll be more conservative with these.